# HTML div element not allocates new line if sibling div element has <a href> alone

Tags: html, css

I am new to HTML and CSS.

In first div I want to display  elements and in second div I want to display text over background image.
But in the result  element is displaying over background image. I want to display  element and in below line I want to display background image. How to achieve this?

Below is my code. I am using HTML and CSS.

```css
.navbar {
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-left {
  float: right;
  width: 25%;
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 14px;
}

.feature {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 25px;
  background: url(https://static3.depositphotos.com/1005590/206/i/950/depositphotos_2068887-stock-photo-lightbulb.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.navbar-Logo {
  float: right;
  color: #dd845a;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="nav-left">
    <a class="navbar-Logo" href="#">LOGO</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="feature">
  <h1> Sample Text</h1>
  <p>Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text.</p>
  <p><a href="#">Engage Now</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. I do not understand your requirements

Comment: Please be more clear about what you're trying to achieve, and a tip for a newbie avoid unnecessarily using the `position: absolute` and `float` properties

Answer (score 0):

Seems you're not understanding the CSS you're using:

- Remove the `float`s, replace the `float:right` with `text-align: right` in `.nav-left`
- Remove `position: absolute` from `.nav-left`

Result below:

```css
.navbar {
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-left {
  text-align: right;
  width: 25%;
  padding-top: 14px;
}

.feature {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 25px;
  background: url(https://static3.depositphotos.com/1005590/206/i/950/depositphotos_2068887-stock-photo-lightbulb.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.navbar-Logo {
  color: #dd845a;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="nav-left">
    <a class="navbar-Logo" href="#">LOGO</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="feature">
  <h1> Sample Text</h1>
  <p>Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text.</p>
  <p><a href="#">Engage Now</a></p>
</div>
```

Setting your `.nav-bar` element to `position: absolute` makes it leave the document flow, and so it will be rendered on top of the next `<div>`.
Using only `float` elements inside a block will make it 0-height with elements overflowing, and so rendered over following elements in document flow.

Answer (score -1):

Change your .navbar css code to this:

```
.navbar
{
height: 120px;
}
```

Comment: If I set fixed height, whether it will work for all screen size and in all devices?

Comment: You can see how it looks for different screens using the zoom in or zoom out option in your browser. The div will always look detached from each other regardless of the screen size.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you are trying to do is that you like to position your link in the navbar to the right within the navbar and the feature div below it.
But the issue is the float property you are using here is taking the applied element out of the document flow, thus pushing the proceeding elements to take it's space.
Here you can use flexbox with justify content property set to flex end to achieve this. Never use float unless it's absolutely necessary.

Answer (score -2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

.navbar
{
   width: 100%;
   border: 2px solid black;
   padding: 35px;
}
    
.nav-left {
  float: right;
  width: 25%;
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
.feature {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 25px;
  background: url(light_bulb.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.navbar-Logo {
    float:right;
  color: #dd845a;
  text-decoration: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="nav-left">
        <a class="navbar-Logo" href="#">LOGO</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="feature">
    <h1> Sample Text</h1>
    <p>Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text.</p>
    <p><a href="#">Engage Now</a></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please give some explanations. We can't even see what you've changed

Comment: .navbar
{
   width: 100%;
   border: 2px solid black;
   padding: 35px;
}


Added Padding top for first div.